# C++ Loop condition doesn't end the loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, infinite-loop

I'm trying to port Artemis Componenty Entity System to C++ to learn a few things. However I'm stuck with a weird problem.

```
void addAll(ImmutableBagInterface<E>& items)
{
    for(auto i = 0u; i < items.size(); ++i)
    {
        add(items.get(i));
    }
}
```

This for loop goes infinitely even though it has a condition. The `items.size()` returns a valid value from what I've seen by printing it using cout. Also I've tried unsigned int and int instead of auto for the iterator however It hasn't changed a thing. I have no idea what is going on.

Heres all of the code for the "ImmutableBag"(which ain't really immutable since I'm using vectors but shhhh noone will know :P)

```
#ifndef IMMUTABLEBAG_H
#define IMMUTABLEBAG_H

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

namespace artemis
{
    template<class E>
    class ImmutableBagInterface
    {
    public:
        virtual ~ImmutableBagInterface(){};
        virtual E get(int index) = 0;
        virtual unsigned int size() = 0;
        virtual bool isEmpty() = 0;
        virtual bool contains(E e) = 0;
    };

    template<class E>
    class Bag : public ImmutableBagInterface<E>
    {
    private:
        std::vector<E> data;
        void init(int capacity)
        {
            data.reserve(capacity);
        }
    public:
        /**
        * Constructs an empty Bag with an initial capacity of 64.
        *
        */
        Bag()
        {
            init(64);
        }

        /**
        * Constructs an empty Bag with the specified initial capacity.
        *
        * @param capacity
        *            the initial capacity of Bag
        */
        Bag(int capacity)
        {
            init(capacity);
        }

        /**
        * Removes the element at the specified position in this Bag. does this by
        * overwriting it was last element then removing last element
        *
        * @param index
        *            the index of element to be removed
        * @return element that was removed from the Bag
        */
        E remove(int index)
        {
            E e = data.at(index);
            data.at(index) = data.back();
            data.pop_back();
            return e;
        }

        /**
        * Remove and return the last object in the bag.
        *
        * @return the last object in the bag, null if empty.
        */
        E removeLast()
        {
            if(!data.empty())
            {
                E e = data.back();
                data.pop_back();
                return e;
            }

            return nullptr;
        }


        /**
        * Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this Bag, if
        * it is present. If the Bag does not contain the element, it is unchanged.
        * does this by overwriting it was last element then removing last element
        *
        * @param e
        *            element to be removed from this list, if present
        * @return <tt>true</tt> if this list contained the specified element
        */
        bool remove(E e)
        {
            for(auto i = 0u; i < data.size(); i++)
            {
                E e2 = data.at(i);
                if(e == e2)
                {
                    data.at(i) = data.back();
                    data.pop_back();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        /**
        * Check if bag contains this element.
        *
        * @param e
        * @return
        */
        bool contains(E e)
        {
            for(auto &v : data)
            {
                if( e == v )
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        /**
        * Removes from this Bag all of its elements that are contained in the
        * specified Bag.
        *
        * @param bag
        *            Bag containing elements to be removed from this Bag
        * @return {@code true} if this Bag changed as a result of the call
        */
        bool removeAll(ImmutableBagInterface<E>& bag)
        {
            bool modified = false;

            for(auto i = 0u; i < bag.size(); i++)
            {
                E e1 = bag.get(i);

                for(auto j = 0u; j < data.size(); j++)
                {
                    E e2 = data.at(j);

                    if(e1 == e2)
                    {
                        remove(j);
                        j--;
                        modified = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return modified;
        }

        /**
        * Returns the element at the specified position in Bag.
        *
        * @param index
        *            index of the element to return
        * @return the element at the specified position in bag
        */
        E get(int index)
        {
            return data.at(index);
        }

        const E get(int index) const
        {
            return data.at(index);
        }

        /**
         * Returns the number of elements in this bag.
         *
         * @return the number of elements in this bag
         */
        unsigned int size()
        {
            return data.size();
        }

        /**
         * Returns the number of elements the bag can hold without growing.
         *
         * @return the number of elements the bag can hold without growing.
         */
        int getCapacity()
        {
            return data.capacity();
        }


        /**
         * Returns true if this list contains no elements.
         *
         * @return true if this list contains no elements
         */
        bool isEmpty()
        {
            return data.empty();
        }

        /**
         * Adds the specified element to the end of this bag. if needed also
         * increases the capacity of the bag.
         *
         * @param e
         *            element to be added to this list
         */
        void add(E e)
        {
            data.push_back(e);
        }

        /**
         * Set element at specified index in the bag.
         *
         * @param index position of element
         * @param e the element
         */
        void set(unsigned int index, E e)
        {
            if(index >= data.size())
            {
                data.resize(index*2);
            }
            data.at(index) = e;
        }

        void grow()
        {
            int newCapacity = (data.capacity() * 3) / 2 + 1;
            grow(newCapacity);
        }

        void grow(int capacity)
        {
            data.resize(capacity);
        }

        void ensureCapacity(int index)
        {
            if(index >= data.capacity())
            {
                data.resize(index * 2);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Removes all of the elements from this bag. The bag will be empty after
         * this call returns.
         */
        void clear()
        {
            data.clear();
        }

        /**
         * Add all items into this bag.
         * @param added
         */
        void addAll(ImmutableBagInterface<E>& items)
        {
            for(auto i = 0u; i < items.size(); ++i)
            {
                add(items.get(i));
            }
        }
    };
}


#endif // IMMUTABLEBAG_H
```

Here's a test where the issue occurs:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "ImmutableBag.h"

int main()
{
    using namespace artemis;
    Bag<std::string> bag;
    Bag<std::string> bag2;

    for(auto i = 0u; i < 20; i++)
    {
        bag2.add("Test");
    }

    bag2.add("Hello");
    bag2.add("World");

    bag.add("Hello");
    std::cout << bag.get(0) << std::endl;
    bag.add("World");
    std::cout << bag.get(1) << std::endl;

    for(auto i = 0u; i < bag2.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << bag2.get(i) << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "==========================" << std::endl;

    bag2.removeAll(bag); //Executes normally (Removes all items, which are identical to any of the items in bag, from bag2)

    for(auto i = 0u; i < bag2.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << bag2.get(i) << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "==========================" << std::endl;

    bag.addAll(bag2); //Infinite loop... NOPE I was an idiot and wrote bag.addAll(bag) instead of bag.addAll(bag2)as Mike Seymour and Thynk Apps pointed out 

    for(auto i = 0u; i < bag.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << bag.get(i) << std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you make this a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) so we can see how `addAll` is being called.

Comment: You're not trying to add a bag to itself, are you? That implementation of `addAll` will loop for ever if you try that.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I added a test case.

Comment: From the code you just posted. you are doing exactly what you cannot do. You are adding `bag` to `bag` which will increase the size by 1 within the loop and loop infinitely. If this is what you want to do, you can set an initial size as loop condition by getting it before loop or by passing it in as a second parameter.

Comment: @ThynkApps yeah... I'm an idiot... I didn't notice that i forgot to add '2'

Comment: @MrPlow typos can be the hardest thing to find especially if you have been staring at your own code for a long time. Simple to overlook, a few extra pairs of eyes is always helpful. Glad you found the issue.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what your `add()` function is doing, but you do realize that if you add inside that loop to the container over which you are looping, you will increase its size by 1, so the for loop can (logically) never terminate? You will in all likelyhood run out of memory before that happens, though.

Comment: unless `items.size()` was zero to start... =)  but probably the problem, yes

Comment: This would only be a problem if the list of items passed in was equal to the container you were adding to. Which I don't know why you would be adding all items to same container, but you could possibly fix this by setting `initialSize = items.size()` then using `i < initialSize` as loop condition

Comment: @Michael I am aware however the loop condition isn't the size of the current container but the size of the container passed to the method. Thus since there are no changes being made to that container I should be exiting smoothly after all the items are added to the current container.

`add()` method just wraps around `push_back()` of the underlying vector so it just adds items to the end of the bag;

Comment: @mark & Thynk, I'm with you on all counts :)

Comment: @MrPlow, then unless you are changing i in your get function (and taking it by reference), I don't see how it can loop forever.

Comment: The evidence is the fact that the loop does not terminate. How else could it not?

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn Neither do I... It's weird. `size()` wraps around vector's `size()` method and `get()` wraps around vector's `at()` so I don't see how or why it would continue infinitely. It's bizzare